# Bulk/Batch Sequence generation with Spring JPA Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I have a Entity class UserContent

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "USER_CONTENT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "USER_CONTENT_ID_SEQ")
public class UserContent {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_CONTENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_CONTENT_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;

...more fields
}
```

At a time I need to save maximum of 7k to 9k UserContents

```
@Repository
public interface UserContentRepositoryV2 extends CrudRepository<UserContent, Long> {
}
```

Here is how i am saving the user contents

```
//assume it has 8K records
List<UserContent> userContents
userContentRepository.save(userContents);
```

Here is my application YAML

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  application:
     name: content
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      jdbc:
        fetch_size: 200
        batch_size: 200
        batch_versioned_data: true
      order_inserts: true
      order_updates: true
      ddl-auto: validate
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"
        jdbc:
          fetch_size: 200
          batch_size: 200
          batch_versioned_data: true
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
```

The problem is when I am trying to save the records, there are thousands of calls to get the id value from sequence first

```
select USER_CONTENT_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual
```

For 8k records first, 8K calls are being made to get the sequence. Hence the whole process is very slow. Once the seqs are there the saves are very fast since batch_size is 200

I am not able to fetch all the sequences faster, i tried using the new sequence strategy as per [best practices point 20](https://dzone.com/articles/50-best-performance-practices-for-hibernate-5-amp) and [Vlad Mihalcea's Blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/)

```
@GenericGenerator(
            name = "USER_CONTENT_ID_GENERATOR",
            strategy = "enhanced-sequence",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                            name = "optimizer",
                            value = "pooled-lo"
                    ),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                            name = "initial_value",
                            value = "1"
                    ),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                            name = "increment_size",
                            value = "1"
                    ),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                            name = "sequence_name",
                            value = "COMMS_USER_CONTENT_ID_SEQ"
                    )
            }
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_CONTENT_ID_GENERATOR")
    private Long id;
```

Even this did not solve the problem.

We are using Oracle 12C and hibernate version is 5.0.12

Will this be better served with JDBC Batch instead of Hibernate?

Thanks for Any help,
Tatha

Comment: Remove that allocationSize=1 from your SequenceGenerator definition to use the default value (50), or even set it to a higher value, then  redefine your database sequence so that its increment has the same value (50, or the value you chose).

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet that worked. Wasn't clear on the concepts of allocationSize